# Set Mongoose model attribute from form data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, meanjs

I am very new to mongodb / mongoose. So new that I am not even sure what words to Google to find the correct answer to my question.

I have a form, it accepts information regarding songs.

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    soundcloud = require('soundcloud-resolve');

/**
 * Song Schema
 */
var SongSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill Song name',
        trim: true
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },

    url: {
        type: String
    },
    youTubeSoundCloudId: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    embed: {
        type: String,
        default: 'No embed.'
    }
});

SongSchema
```

On the form itself, it only accepts name, and url. The rest of the information for the model can be derived from those two things. How do I set these? I am using API's to get the other information. I know how to get the information from the API's, just not how or where to literally set the data in. I believe it is in this same file... But I am unsure.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a model for the schema like this

`var Song = mongoose.model('songs', SongSchema)`

*where songs is your collection name*

Now, you can create an object for the schema

`var song = new Song()`

and set the various attributes like,

`song.name =`

`song.url =`

`song.user =`

`song.youTubeSoundCloudId =`, etc.